# Dynamically getting the property_id using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a table that is dynamically generated. And in the table I have a button called `view images`. Every time this button is clicked, I need to get the image names from database for that particular property.

```
        <?php foreach($unapproved as $unapp):?>
        <td>
        <div id="#imagedisplay">
            <input id="property" type="text" value="<?php  echo $unapp->property_id; ?>" style="display :none">

        </div>

        <br/><b>Title : <?php  echo $unapp->title; ?></b> <br/><?php  echo nl2br($unapp->full_description); ?></td>
        <td>
            <a  id="view_image" class="btn btn-default" >View Images</a><br/><br/><br/>
            <a  class="btn btn-default" style="color:Green;">Approve</a><br/><br/><br/>
            <a  class="btn btn-default" style="color:red;">Delete</a>
        </td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Every time the `view images` is clicked, need to get the value (property_id) from `<input id="property" type="text" value="<?php  echo $unapp->property_id; ?>" style="display :none">` using jquery. so that i can do the ajax call.

My problem is, I want to get the `property_id` of the clicked. I tried this way but it works only for the first property.

```
  <script>
$('#view_image').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var prop_id = $('#property').val();
    console.log(prop_id);
});
</script>
```

application looks like this

[image]

Simple words, I need the `property_id` of the clicked property.

Can anyone give me suggestions to get the id of the clicked property?

Comment: You cannot use the same id for multiple html elements. This way you will get only value of first one.

Comment: `id` should be unique. Right now you are setting the same `id` to every `$unapp`. How is the software going to know which one you need? Add the `$unapp->property_id` to the ids of button and image

Comment: i can dynamically `eg:#viewimage28` give a id, but how can i get the clicked property id from it. in jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this issue, but one easy way is adding an data attribute to your link:

```
<a class="view_image btn btn-default" data-property-id="<?php echo $unapp->property_id; ?>">View Images</a>
```

and then changing your script to:

```
$('.view_image').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var prop_id = $(this).data('property-id');
    console.log(prop_id);
});
```

Just as bonusinfo: It is not allowed to have multiple elements with the same `id`. Use class' instead.

Comment: tnx. it solves my problem for now. I am curious to know other ways also. please give me some good tutorial links. if possible. tnx.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any good links that fits this. I could add another answer, with a few more though.